# What are the steps to host Angular 8 app on Namecheap with a Namecheap domain name?

Tags: angular, gitlab, namecheap

I have tried to find a decent answer all over the place but to no avail! I have complete my angular app that is currently in GitLab! I have a domain `example.com` on Namecheap.com and now I am trying to figure out and understand how I can deploy my app to that domain name. Your input is much appreciated! There is no backend, its all front end!

Comment: Do you have ftp access? after a build, upload the contents ofthe dist folder where index.html is and its sub folder and all files to your websites HTML directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy any app you need to have/buy a hosting first. Then you can upload your app to hosting and link hosting to your domain. You can choose any hosting provider like DigitalOcean, DreamHost, Godady, etc. You can do it on Namecheap too https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/

There are several options for hosting on Namecheap (that is relevant to your task):

- [Shared hosting](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/shared/)
- [VPS hosting](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/vps/)
- [dedicated servers](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/dedicated-servers/)

Here is a step-by-step instruction on how to upload your app to shared hosting using Namecheap domain name https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/how-to-set-up-hosting-account/

For Dedicated and VPS hosting you need to configure it first.

If you don't have a backend, I recommend you to use AWS S3 bucket as a server. It's super easy to configure, very cheap (it might be eligible for free Tier for 1st year - need to check). Here is [an instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html) on how to upload your built app to S3 bucket and make it available as a website. Once you deployed it will be availble via some service address. To link your domain name this S3 bucket use a CloudFront service. Instruction is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/).